# Use same directive in same view and bind different data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, highcharts, scope

I have created a custom directive for displaying a charts made with the Highcharts library.

Now I want to build upon this directive and create multiple charts in the same view.

This is not possible with the current code I have, as you can see below.

How can I organize my code so that it's possible to bind different data to it in the same view?

Below is some example code to illustrate the problem.

**Directive**

```
 function dateChart() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      title: '@'
    },
    template: '<div id="chart"></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var chart;

      function createChart() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
          chart: {
          title: scope.title
        });
      }
```

**Controller**

```
vm.title = "My Chart";
```

**html-template**

```
  <date-chart></date-chart>

  <date-chart></date-chart>
```

Comment: multiple instances of same directive means you should make use of isolated scope. I think you are in right direction here. Just attach different titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to tell the directive that data will be passed along

```
 function dateChart() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      title: '@'
      chartData: '='
    },
    template: '<div id="chart"></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var chart;

      function createChart() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
          chart: {
          title: scope.title
        });
      }
```

So if the data for your charts is at `$scope.someData1` and `$scope.someData2` you can pass it along like this:

```
<date-chart chart-data="someData1"></date-chart>

<date-chart chart-data="someData2"></date-chart>
```