# Using Same Directive for Different Data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am a little new to Angular directives and was wondering if there was a way to use the same directive multiple times but bind in different data? (im sure theres a way i just dont know how!)

For example, i have the following two tables which i'd like to make into 1 directive and just pass in data differently:

1.Here i am repeating through an array of objects, if the kv isPaint:true then i will print the following table..

```
<tr class="hover"
     ng-repeat="paint in allOptions | orderBy: 'listPrice'"
     ng-if="paint.isPaint"
     ng-click="addRemoveOption(paint)"
     ng-class="{'selected':isSelected(paint)}"
      >
    <td> {{ paint.code }}</td>
    <td> {{ paint.name }}</td>
    <td> {{ paint | includedOption }}</td>
    <td> {{ paint.disclaimer }}</td>
    <td> {{ paint.salesGroup }}</td>
    <td> {{ paint.optionPrev}}</td>
    <td> {{ paint.familyCode }}</td>

</tr>
```

2. I am doing the same here except i am checking for trims..

   ```
    <tr class="hover"
      ng-repeat="trim in allOptions | orderBy: 'listPrice'"
      ng-if="trim.isTrim"
      ng-click="addRemoveOption(trim)" 
      ng-class="{'selected':isSelected(trim)}"
     >
       <td> {{ trim.code }}</td>
       <td> {{ trim.name }}</td>
       <td> {{ trim | includedOption }}</td>
       <td> {{ trim.disclaimer }}</td>
       <td> {{ trim.salesGroup }}</td>
       <td> {{ trim.optionPrev }}</td>
       <td> {{ trim.familyCode }}</td>
     </tr>
   ```

I only need access to the controller from the page where the directive would be used so i have access to 'allOptions'. I suppose i can do this by setting scope:true in the directive?

I can easily change the ng-repeat names to be more general, then i would only really need to change the ng-if to be the main determinant if a value should be printed in the table. All table columns, data, etc. are EXACTLY the same, i just need to be able to seperate trims, paints, options, etc. I found a similiar post [Use same directive in same view and bind different data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39991627/use-same-directive-in-same-view-and-bind-different-data) but I really have no idea what is going on here...

Thank you for the help, if there is any additional information that i can provide please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple directive to repeat a list:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      list: '='
    },
    template: '<div ng-repeat="item in list">{{item.name}}</div>',

    replace: true,
    //require: 'ngModel',
    link: function($scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

    }
  };
});
```

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1LTSOB?p=preview)

This should get you started.

Comment: I will have to change my data model a little to make this work but i believe this is the correct answer. But, i probably should've had my data model this way to begin with :). Thanks again!